# VC++ SQL INSERT INTO error

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-c++

I'm using VC++ (Visual C++) in my system. I'm doing to add student's information in a Access Database which I used SQL Command (INSERT INTO).

this is my codes to add student's information in access database

```
         OleDb::OleDbConnection^ con = gcnew OleDb::OleDbConnection();
         OleDb::OleDbCommand^ command = gcnew OleDb::OleDbCommand();
         con->ConnectionString::set(conStr);
         con->Open();

String^ cmdTxt = "
    insert into students(studno, fname, lname,
         mname, gender, status, birthday, course, shift, section, homeadd,
         provadd, contactnum, nameguard, addguard, contguard, sec1, sub1,
         room1, unit1, guro1, sec2, sub2, room2, unit2, guro2, sec3, sub3,
         room3, unit3, guro3, sec4, sub4, room4, unit4, guro4, sec5, sub5,
         room5, unit5, guro5, sec6, sub6, room6, unit6, guro6, sec7, sub7, 
         room7, unit7, guro7, sec8, sub8, room8, unit8, guro8, sec9, sub9,
         room9, unit9, guro9, sec10, sub10, room10, unit10, guro10)
    values('" + studno + "', '" + fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + mname + "', 
    '" + sex + "', '" + status + "', '" + birthday + "', '" + course + "',
    '" + shift + "', '" + section + "', '" + homeAdd + "', '" + provAdd + "', 
    '" + contactnum + "', '" + nameGuardian + "', '" + addGuardian + "',
    '" + numGuardian + "', '" + se1 + "', '" + sub1 + "', '" + room1 + "',
    '" + unit1 + "', '" + guro1 + "', '" + se2 + "', '" + sub2 + "', 
    '" + room2 + "', '" + unit2 + "', '" + guro2 + "', '" + se3 + "', 
    '" + sub3 + "', '" + room3 + "', '" + unit3 + "', '" + guro3 + "', 
    '" + se4 + "', '" + sub4 + "','" + room4 + "', '" + unit4 + "', 
    '" + guro4 + "', '" + se5 + "', '" + sub5 + "', '" + room5 + "', 
    '" + unit5 + "', '" + guro5 + "', '" + se6 + "', '" + sub6 + "', 
    '" + room6 + "', '" + unit6 + "', '" + guro6 + "', '" + se7 + "', 
    '" + sub7 + "', '" + room7 + "', '" + unit7 + "', '" + guro7 + "', 
    '" + se8 + "', '" + sub8 + "', '" + room8 + "', '" + unit8 + "', 
    '" + guro8 + "', '" + se9 + "', '" + sub9 + "', '" + room9 + "', 
    '" + unit9 + "', '" + guro9 + "', '" + se10 + "', '" + sub10 + "', 
    '" + room1 + "', '" + unit10 + "', '" + guro10 + "')";
         command->Connection::set(con);
         command->CommandText::set(cmdTxt);
         command->ExecuteNonQuery();
         con->Close();
```

No errors found when i compiled and run it, the problems is when i add student's information shows an error message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

i checked many times in INSERT INTO, so i changed it

```
             command->CommandText::set("insert into students("
             + "studno,"
             + "fname," 
             + "lname," 
             + "mname,"
             + "gender,"
             + "status,"
             + "birthday,"
             + "course,"
             + "shift)"
             + "values("
             + "'" + studno + "', '"
             + fname + "', '"
             + lname + "', '"
             + mname + "', '"
             + sex + "', '"
             + status + "', '"
             + birthday + "', '"
             + course + "', '"
             + shift + "')");
```

This code is works 100%, so I add fields,

```
             command->CommandText::set("insert into students("
             + "studno,"
             + "fname," 
             + "lname," 
             + "mname,"
             + "gender,"
             + "status,"
             + "birthday,"
             + "course,"
             + "shift,"
             + "section)"
             + "values("
             + "'" + studno + "', '"
             + fname + "', '"
             + lname + "', '"
             + mname + "', '"
             + sex + "', '"
             + status + "', '"
             + birthday + "', '"
             + course + "', '"
             + shift + "', '"
             + section + "')");
```

so it gives me an error. -_-

so how to solve this problem

Comment: Change `"section)"` to `"[section])"`

Comment: ohh, it's works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SECTION` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#S).  If you surround that name with square brackets, Access will understand it is a field name.  So change `"section)"` to `"[section])"`